# How to find the area below axes in pixel values

Tags: matlab, position, matlab-guide, axes

Is there a command that returns the coordinates of the area underneath the axes, in pixel units?

Something like the `findobj(gcf,'tag','axes1')`?

I need these coordinates so that I can place a slider exactly under an axes on the same figure.

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is that you want to accomplish? Do you want to determine how large the axes are when rendered on the screen? Or are you attempting to obtain a handle to the pixel buffer of the rendered axes?

Comment: I just want to place a slider exactly under an axes on the same figure

Comment: I have edited your question to include this information. You can always >[edit]< your question yourself to clarify and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB `axes` objects, just like all other types of graphics objects, have a set of properties that you can query and modify. Read the [documentation for the axes properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html) to learn what is modifiable.

Just like the `uicontrol` object that you intend to place, the `axes` object has a `Position` property. However, by default, `axes.Position` is in normalized units, whereas `uicontrol.Position` is in pixels.

You can set the `axes.Units` property to `'pixels'`, after that you can query and modify the object's position in pixels:

```
ah = gca;
ah.Units = 'pixels';
p = ah.OuterPosition;
p(4) = p(2);
p(2) = 0;
uicontrol('style','slider','position',p)
```

NB: I use the `axes.Outerposition` property so that the slider is below the labels, the `axes.Position` property is the box around the axes lines themselves, without any labels.